# Qt Creator needs a compiler set up to build. Configure a compiler in kit options

Tags: qt, gcc, compiler-construction, qt-creator, qt5

I just installed Qt 5.2 package on ubuntu. I simply created a Qt widget application, and when I tried to build it, I got the following message:

> Qt Creator needs a compiler set up to build. Configure a compiler in
>   kit options

I have tried several things, all of which were unsuccessful. I tried setting the compiler kit to

> Desktop Qt 5.2.0 GCC 32bit (default)
>   [image]

However it didn't work

After that I set the compiler to

> GCC (x86 32bit in use/bin)
>   [image]

However that didn't work either.

I also tried adding gcc manually and gave it the path

> /usr/bin/g++-4.6

but it still didn't work.

This is what appears in there Qt Version tab

[image]

This is what I get when I remove the .pro.user file and restart the IDE, Whats the difference between configuring a project as Desktop and Desktop Qt 5.2.0 GCC 32bit?
[image]

Comment: What happens when you click on the Debug/Release button in the bottom left (right above the run arrow) ?  Do you have options to choose from there?

Comment: I only created a release version

Comment: What shows up in the Qt Versions tab in tools->options?

Comment: Qt Creator usually have no problem setting up a default kit. Please, try to remove your `.pro.user` file and restart the IDE. This once fixed for me the same problem.

Comment: It builds if I configure the project as Desktop Qt 5.2.0 GCC 32bit

Comment: On the first screenshot you have manual "Desktop" build configuration marked with red circle. You have probably created your own build configuration accidentally but forgot to set it up (specify compiler, Qt version and so on), that's why Qt Creator fails to build the project for this configuration.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16497442/2624806 might help.

Answer (score 1):

Qt Creator needs a version of tools that are able to link against the Qt binaries that the downloaded package contains. In your case, the local toolchain and the binaries don't match. That means that you would actually have to build the Qt with your toolkit and make sure that QtCreator can find the built binaries.

The simpler way for Ubuntu is to use the packaged version of the tools; they play well with the already delivered binaries. Use `sudo apt-get install qtcreator` to install it with all the dependencies.