# Qt creator needs a compiler

Tags: qt-creator

I have problem with Qt compiler.The error is:

Qt Creator needs a compiler set up to build. Configure a compiler in the kit options.
the code is:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include<QLabel>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    //   MainWindow w;
    //   w.show();

    QLabel *lb=new QLabel();
    lb->settext("first label");
    lb->setvisible(true);


    return a.exec();
}
```

The version of Qt is 5.3.0 and I have visual studio 2010.

In internet I read the version of Qt must be compatible with visual studio.

I want to know is problem from the version of the Qt and visual studio or another thing?

Comment: Did you try what [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17545313/4342498) answer suggest?

Comment: Options . Build&Run - Compilers - add yours to the list. You will also need the Qt libraries themselves built for MSVC. From the same window, use the MSVC compiler and the Qt version for it to create a Kit.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Qt Creator needs a compiler set up to build. Configure a compiler in the kit options](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14700965/qt-creator-needs-a-compiler-set-up-to-build-configure-a-compiler-in-the-kit-opt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Qt Creator needs a compiler set up to build. Configure a compiler in
>   the kit options.

From the menu of QtCreator, Open "Tools>Options>Build&Run>Kits". If no auto-detected configuration, you need configure it manually.

In addition, make sure Qt5.3.0 is compiled with VS2010. If not, download the correct version, or compile Qt source code yourself.