# QT 5.6.0 MSVC2015 32bit "Qt Creator needs a compiler set up to build"

Tags: windows, qt

I think the vs complier has been installed,but the creator raise error: 
08:57:30: Configuration is faulty. Check the Issues view for details.
Error while building/deploying project standalone (kit: Desktop Qt 5.6.0 MSVC2015 32bit)
When executing step "Make".
:-1: **error: Qt Creator needs a compiler set up to build**. Configure a compiler in the kit options.
Some env information：
System info: Win10 professional 64bit
VS info : visual studio 2015 professional update2
Qt : QT 5.6.0 MSVC2015 32bit,ABI:x86-windows-msvc2015-pe-32bit,intalled from file qt-opensource-windows-x86-msvc2015-5.6.0.exe
Qt creator auto-detected 5 compiler whit type MSVC, such as "Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler 14.0 (x86)".
[Click to see screenshot of creator auto-detected 5 compliers:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWLH4.jpg)

I do not know much about QT and want to learn.
I have searched many similar questions by google but no answer sloved my problem！
Thank anyone for solution;

Answer (score 1):

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14700965/qt-creator-needs-a-compiler-set-up-to-build-configure-a-compiler-in-the-kit-opt?rq=1) answer slolvee my problem，even though I don't know why.
Thanks!

I copy the answer here:
**i was also having the same problem so what i did is

For linux

sudo apt-get install g++ 

sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dev libglu1-mesa-dev

and then closed the qt creator and restarted it and it worked

i do not know which of the above two made it work but it worked !!

For Windows

Delete this file C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\QtProject\qtcreator\toolchains.xml to solve the problem.

answered May 11 '13 at 13:10

Subham Tripathi**