# QT creator on raspberry pi GUI

Tags: python, c++, linux, pyqt, raspberry-pi3

IM trying to create a GUI on QT creator with a raspberry pi 3. Every time I put a widget and try to run it to check if its working, this message shows up "QT Creator needs a compiler set up to build. Configure a compiler in the kit options.

I'm not sure what to do about this!

Comment: QT Creator is for C++ code so it needs C++ compiler.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Qt Creator needs a compiler set up to build. Configure a compiler in the kit options](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14700965/1889329).

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between running QT on a raspberry pi and a normal computer. First of all, which OS are you running? QT just needs a compiler to use. Just install gcc or clang compiler and you will be fine. Next time just read the output carefully. Configure a compiler in the kit options means there is no compiler!

Comment: Im using raspberry pi 3, and I downloaded python 2 and 3. I downloaded these: sudo apt-get install g++ 
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dev libglu1-mesa-dev? are those similar to gcc or clang? if not, how do I download them?

Comment: There's a metapackage called build-essential which should install the compiler and a bunch of related/needed packages:

[code]sudo apt-get install build-essential[/code]

Comment: Install these, try again, and comment if you have a problem!

Comment: I still get an error saying in compile output:  error while building/deploying project GUI (kit:desktop) when exciting step "Make" and in the issues: QT creator needs a compiler set up to build. Configure a compiler in the kit options

Answer (score 0):

I will assume you already have gcc 4.9 installed on your RPi.

Tools --> Options
Build & Run --> Compilers Tab
The compiler path should be /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-4.9