# Cannot run compiler 'cl'

Tags: c++, qt

I have installed Qt on Windows according to the instructions, but when I have created a Qt Widget application I am getting the following error:

```
Running Windows Runtime device detection.
No winrtrunner.exe found.
Project ERROR: Cannot run compiler 'cl'. Maybe you forgot to setup the environment?
```

Also, in my Qt Creator project directory I cannot see anything apart from my `.pro` file.

I have tried with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36559546/6366458), but could not get any result.

In my Qt installation folder, when I open the `Tools` folder, it just has `QtCreator` folder and no compiler folder.

- Qt installed: 5.9.1
- IDE: Qt Creator

How to fix this error?

Comment: Did you install a compiler? `cl` is part of visual studio which you need to install separately. Alternatively run the maintenancetool again and tell it to install mingw gcc 5.3.

Comment: Addition to above, i had a lot of issues with Qt installation, what is important - having previously installed VS2015/VS2013 is cure for most of the issues. In my case, using offline Qt installer with VS2015, after installing the VS2015 itselft have worked just fine. EDIT: Also, i needed to open VS2015 before the installation and create the C++ project, i just realized the lack of C++ packages, which just get downloaded! I had only C# before that.

Comment: @Guillotine Right now I am trying with the online installer and will install the compiler also with it and check.

Right now avoiding to install the heavy VS.

Comment: You will need to reinstall your complete Qt since if you installed the version that requires the Visual C++ compiler, the Qt libs have been compiled with it and mixing different compiler in a single project is a bad idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So after lots of struggle and research I am finally able to install Qt and run the program using Qt Creator in Windows.

- For Qt to run you need a compiler and a debugger, which is not provided by default.
- If you just have to run a Qt-only program and the extra libraries that you will be using will compile using MinGW, then you can select MinGW as the compiler during the time of installation using online Qt installer.
- But in most cases, we will be installing Visual Studio first. Select C++/CLI in the checkbox, as it's not selected by default.
- Once Visual Studio is installed, we need a separate debugger CDB to link Qt with VS. For that, you need to uninstall the current Windows Software Development Kit and install again from [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk), or modify the installation in the Windows Settings app. During the installation, **make sure to select `Debugging Tool For Windows`**. The reason for uninstalling previously was that if we install again with the new option also selected, it will not override the previous installation.
- Now open the Qt project. Go to `Tools > Options > Build & Run > Debuggers` and you can see that the debugger should be auto-detected.
- Now go to the kits tab and select the debugger that was detected. For the compiler, select the required compiler, you will see a warning that the compiler is not compatible but you can ignore that as the program runs. (Don't forget to select Apply).

Answer (score 1):

In my case, before running ANY `qmake` commands, I had to run `%QT_DIR%\bin\qtenv2.bat` manually, which needs to be modified to call the `vcvarsall.bat`.

With VS 2017 community, add this line to `qtenv2.bat`

```
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" x64
```

Replace x64 with whatever architecture you have.

To verify your VS-Qt toolchain is correctly installed:

1. Open QtCreator
2. Go to `Options > Kits`, ensure that you have expected Qt versions, compilers, and debuggers under the designated tabs. Those names are suffixed with VS versions and architectures.